# I'm creating a Repl for a Discord bot, and websocket has an error

Tags: node.js, websocket, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm currently creating a Discord bot in Repl and this is my first bot. I've hooked it up to a WebSocket and now I'm getting this error:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)

Here is my current code:

```js
//Discord Things
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

//Websocket Server For Discord Things
const WebSocket = require('ws');
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:3000');
socket.onopen = () => {
  //code to be executed, when the websocket connection was opened
  console.log("Connection made!");
}

socket.onclose = event => {
  console.log(`Connection closed with code ${event.code}.`);
}

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.say("Connected :)");
});
```

Comment: what is the purpose of creating a websocket here? it seems like ur trying to connect to a websocket server hosted on the repl itself, but u didnt host one there (why would you host a server at the same place)

Comment: Oh wait yeah I'm dumb, I don't know how I didn't realize that thanks